# How to trace a net in Altium Designer viewer (search for all places a signal is used)?

Tags: altium

Given a net or off-sheet symbol, how can I follow the entire net, and (this part is important) step through all connections on all sheets?

It seems like a simple thing, but I just can't find it.

The Navigator Panel->Navigator is fine, but still only searches one sheet:

[image]

Comment: I think its Alt+Left click, or Ctrl+Left click.

Comment: If you already have a pcb with the net on it, you also can use the cross-probe. This will highlight the whole net on all schematic sheets.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is the "*Navigator-Panel*" of Altium. 
On the bottom right click on "Design Compiler" then on "Navigator".  Now "compile" your project.

[image]
Altium provides a useful manual:

http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/WorkspaceManager_Pnl-Navigator%28%28Navigator%29%29_AD

There is also a good video from Robert Feranec on the topic of how to propperly check your schematic. It can be found on Youtube:

https://youtu.be/CDAuCchchtI

Comment: Ok, but as far as I can tell that's just one sheet. How can I find the net on all sheets?

Comment: If you click on the Net on the "Net/Bus" Tab and then expand this field, you see all associated Pins. By clicking one of the pins you jump directly to this pin, regardless on which sheet it is. So all sheets are covered in this.

Answer (score 2):

http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/PCB+Editor+Shortcuts

please examine this document.

The Answer is CTRL + Left-click

Comment: Ok, but that's just on one sheet. How can I find the net on all sheets?

Answer (score 1):

So far the best I've found is "navigate heirarchy".  Activate the up/down arrow on the tool bar.  Now you can click on an off-sheet symbol and cycle through all the pages it goes to:

[image: Altium - Find net on all sheets]

Pretty awkward though.

Answer (score 1):

Altium Designer 19.1.5 is ALT + Left-Click.